# How to make the list row onClick open url referenced from XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, url

I have a class with a list and when each list is pressed it is meant to open a URL within an activity that's just a webview. the list works with xml parsing and the parsed xml has the  tag . Thanks in advance.

like so:

```
  <article>
<id>Arts and Culture</id>
<title>Nash Grier</title>
<author> Jessica Carradine</author>
<desc>Nash Grier is a 16-year-old YouTube, Vine, and Twitter superstar whose fan base is primarily teenage girls who are obsessed with his dazzling blue eyes</desc>
<thumb_url>http://graffiti.hostoi.com/00Graffiti00/Photos/Art/nash.png</thumb_url>
<key>http://graffiti.hostoi.com/00Graffiti00/Articles/Art/nash.html</key>
</article>
```

and the class looks like so

```
public class Arti extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://graffiti.hostoi.com/00Graffiti00/lists/arts.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
static final String KEY_LINK = "key";


ListView list;
LazyAdapteri adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.arti);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    if(Utils.connectivity(getBaseContext()))
    {
        new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute(URL);
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please connect to working internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Arti.this, Article.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra("b", "KEY_LINK");
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    });

}

class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapteri(Arti.this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void execute(String url) {

    }
}
}
```

webiview acticivit:

public class Article extends Activity{
    private WebView webview;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.articleview);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String KEY_LINK = b.getString("b");

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.loadUrl(KEY_LINK);



}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What results are you currently getting? I see you're passing in a Bundle parameter as an Intent extra, but the Bundle is empty. You need to first put the KEY_LINK inside the Bundle or just pass the string directly in the Intent using

```
Intent.putExtra("key", KEY_LINK);
```

EDIT: Also, when you pass in KEY_LINK as an extra, you should remove the quotations. You're referencing a variable, not passing in the literal string "KEY_LINK"

EDIT 2: Ok, so there's no need to use Bundle here. You're not passing it your own objects(Like Parcelables, for instance) and there's nifty methods already in place for passing in Strings, ints, doubles, etc.

In your Arti Activity, you can pass in the URL like this

```
intent.putExtra("key", KEY_LINK);
```

And in your WebView Activity you can simple retrieve the passed string like this

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key);
```

Then load that url in your webview like you're already doing

```
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: right now I just get the new activity open blank web view but I'm not exactly sure what you mean on passing the string. thats exactly what im missing but i dont get how to put it in thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving the String that you passed in?(KEY_LINK). For one, you are incorrectly passing the url into the new activity, so that is why a blank webview is showing. It would also be useful to share the code in your webview activity

Comment: thank you but the getStringExtra has an error about how it cant be referenced form static content and the Intent.putStringExtra("key", KEY_LINK); cant resolve method

Comment: My mistake, the intent method is intent.putExtra("key", KEY_LINK). I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for all your help but webview still renders nothing. this is the last line of the logcat when initiate the onclick (56)] Async pixel transfers not supported